# All fillable fields clear when I open a pdf

Tags: pdf, acrobat

In my program I load and edit .pdf files. These files print with the correct data in the fillable fields just fine. However when I save them to file and open them the fields contain data momentarily and then are cleared. I'm wondering if anyone has any insight as to why this is happening. I tried looking for javascript within the files that might be causing this and can't find any. I also tried recreating the fields and altering the reset button on the form so that it wouldn't clear anything, just in case something was calling it. I have researched this for most of the day and all my efforts have been fruitless. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please share a sample PDF.

Comment: Since I can't attach a file here. The file is a dmv form and is readily accessible here: http://dmv.ny.gov/forms/ds872.pdf

Comment: How are you changing the fields? What tools are you using? Do the fields have appearance streams? Are you honoring and updating those?

Comment: Here's an example of a form that clears pages on load using per-page JavaScript.  This is a tax form.  It was saving all my data then clearing it when I reloaded the form.  Very frustrating.  I was able to remove the actions as per @Max Wyss below ::   https://www.colorado.gov/pacific/sites/default/files/106Book.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form is secured. To noodle around with that form, you'd have to contact the issuer and ask for a non-secured version.

However, the symptoms look as if it has a reset on open functionality. As you have not found anything using JavaScript, the reset is not done with JavaScript, but as an Action. And Actions can be run from the pageOpen event.

Comment: Indeed, the single PDF page has an **AA** entry triggering **ResetForm** for all fields in the document upon opening the page.

Comment: I have an unsecured version of the pdf that is editable. Where would I find the pageOpen event? I looked in action wizard and I can't find it. I am using Adobe Acrobat DC Pro by the way.

Comment: Just for the records… In Acrobat, the PageOpen event can be found as follows: Open the Pages/Thumbnails left hand panel. Select the page, and open the context menu (usually right-click). Select the Page Properties… item, which opens the Page Properties dialog. Switch to the Actions tab, and there you are…

Comment: This may not have much value, but I thought it was worth it to mention that this can also be accessed by dragging the mouse down towards the bottom of the screen, hovering over the overlapping page icon displayed on the toolbox that pops up (it should say show/hide page thumbnails), clicking it, then following the steps detailed in the response by Max Wyss.

Comment: That's valuable as well; it is another way to get to the thumbnails…

Answer (score 1):

Page 1 in the additional actions (AA) dictionary has an action tree for the Page Opened event which is a reset form action. There's the culprit.